# How to pass thw Viewdata to all the views in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a dropdown list which select a value

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Screenname(FormCollection collection)
    {
        Viewdata["screenname"] = collection[0];

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ScreenName = ViewData["screenname"] });
    }
```

then i want to access this ViewData in other actions like this

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, string screenname)
    {
        try
        {
            /// thats my dataobject which creates 

            DataObj.SaveData(Guid.Empty, collection, screenname);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ScreenName = ViewData["screenname"] });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

where index looks like this ...

```
    public ActionResult Index(string ScreenName)
    {
        ///thats my list 
        GetTable = new GetDataTable(ScreenName);

        return View(GetTable);
    }
```

First when i select the value and index gets executed properly.... but when i try to access the viewdata again it doesn't contain the value so anybody if please can help ...
or alternate method to save and retrieve data .

Comment: Do NOT use the currently accepted answer (static variable passing).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used a view to take the data from the user and then saved it to a static variable and then used this variable to pass the data to all the other views .

Thanks anyways

Comment: Terrible!!! solution. Every user will get the same static variable set and if another user accesses the page in between the redirect of a second user then the second user will get the first's value. DO NOT USE THIS ANYONE.

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewData` object is specific for the particular action that is executing. To pass data between actions, use `TempData`. more on [the difference between the two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) on MSDN.

You can also directly write to the session state through the [`Controller.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

This has actually been covered quite often here.  The solution for now is to use TempData to save the data you need before you use RedirectToAction().

If you do a search for "RedirectToAction" you'll find a number of posts covering this topic, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672143/mvc-passing-data-with-redirecttoaction).

The next official release of the framework will fix this.

Comment: Even When i use tempdata i am not able to access the data . it still remains null . i have already tried that ...any other options

Comment: plus i have few more actions i want to pass the data to so please anyone help