# HttpGet Attribute ignored on RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller with an action Review like so:

```
    [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    [RoleRequired("Payroll Tech")]
    public ActionResult Review(ReviewModel model)
    {
        PayrollManagement.Importer importer = new PayrollManagement.Importer(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImportDatabase"].ConnectionString,
            model);

        model.Discrepancies = importer.GetDiscrepancyReport();
        return View(model);
    }

    [RoleRequired("Payroll Tech")]
    public ActionResult Review()
    {
        ReviewModel model = new ReviewModel();
        model.Initialize();  //initializes the dropdown collections
        model.Discrepancies = new List<DiscrepancyReportItem>();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I am trying to invoke this method on a RedirectToAction call from my Upload method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RoleRequired("Payroll Tech")]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadModel model)
    {
        string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        model.File.SaveAs(tmpFile);
        PayrollManagement.Importer importer = new PayrollManagement.Importer(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImportDatabase"].ConnectionString,
            model);

        importer.UploadExcelDocument(tmpFile);
        return RedirectToAction("Review", (IImporterFileInfo)model);
    }
```

This seems to work appropriately, in that when the Upload event is called, the redirect adds the model elements to the URL, which I would expect to be mapped to the ReviewModel object.

Instead, the generic Review (not HttpPost or HttpGet) is invoked, which is not what I would expect.  Why is it not mapping to the model and persisting the data?  What can I do to make the core data in the IImporterFileInfo interface carry on to the next screen, wizard-like?

I will include the model structure as well, so ppl can see what I'm trying to do.

```
public class BaseModel : IImporterFileInfo
{

    [Display(Name = "Financial System:")]
    public string FinancialSystem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fiscal Year:")]
    public int FiscalYear { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fiscal Week:")]
    public int FiscalWeek { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Accrual File?")]
    public bool IsAccrual { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Accrual Month:")]
    public int AccrualMonth { get; set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.FinancialSystem = "Legacy";
        this.FiscalWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        this.FiscalYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        this.AccrualMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    }

    //the readonly lists
    private IList<string> _FinancialSystems;
    public IList<string> FinancialSystems
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FinancialSystems == null)
            {
                IList<string> choices = new List<string>();
                choices.Add("Legacy");
                choices.Add("Morris");
                _FinancialSystems = choices;
                //_FinancialSystems = new SelectList(choices, this.FinancialSystem ?? "Legacy");
            }
            return _FinancialSystems;
        }
    }

    private IList<int> _FiscalWeeks;
    public IList<int> FiscalWeeks
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FiscalWeeks == null)
            {
                IList<int> choices = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 53; i++)
                {
                    choices.Add(i);
                }
                _FiscalWeeks = choices;
            }
            return _FiscalWeeks;
        }
    }

    private IList<int> _FiscalYears;
    public IList<int> FiscalYears
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FiscalYears == null)
            {
                IList<int> choices = new List<int>();
                for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year - 7; i <= DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
                {
                    choices.Add(i);
                }
                _FiscalYears = choices;
            }
            return _FiscalYears;
        }
    }

    private IList<int> _AccrualMonths;
    public IList<int> AccrualMonths
    {
        get
        {
            if (_AccrualMonths == null)
            {
                IList<int> choices = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
                {
                    choices.Add(i);
                }
                _AccrualMonths = choices;
            }
            return _AccrualMonths;
        }
    }

}

public class UploadModel : BaseModel
{
    [Display(Name = "File Name:")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewModel : BaseModel
{
    public IList<DiscrepancyReportItem> Discrepancies { get; set; }
}
```

I think this should work pretty well.  Dunno why it doesn't.  The query string looks like:

```
https://localhost:44301/Import/Review?File=System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper&FinancialSystem=Legacy&FiscalYear=2011&FiscalWeek=33&IsAccrual=True&AccrualMonth=8&FinancialSystems=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.String%5D&FiscalWeeks=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.Int32%5D&FiscalYears=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.Int32%5D&AccrualMonths=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.Int32%5D
```

Comment: the model is being mapped to url elements? you can't pass a model in a RedirectToAction call

Comment: Why not?  If you pass values in a Get, they normally populate the model don't they?  The URL query string has the appropriate values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this question, one option you could do is use TempData, hold the model or whatever you will need in the next call

[MVC - Passing Data with RedirectToAction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672143/mvc-passing-data-with-redirecttoaction)

Comment: yeah, this will work, but it seems... inelegant.  Why won't the mapper instantiate my object based off of GET values as well as POST variables?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a ReviewModel instance and pass it on the redirect.

Comment: you can't pass a model in a redirect call, you can only pass route values (decompose the model into individual tokens)

Comment: The ReviewModel is very similar to the UploadModel... the important information I wish to persist is in the common base class, and all other properties are perfectly fine as nulls.  Most of the time these map back to the appropriate objects.  The problem isn't the mapping; it's the fact that the system does not recognize there is something to map.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing upload model to a method which is expecting a ReviewModel. You need to pass a ReviewModel.

Comment: The model is broken down into its public properties upon the redirect.  I really don't think that's the issue.