# Maintain URL after Post in asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

Fairly new to asp.net mvc I don't have knowledge to change the way certain things work. Here is one of them

1. Controller Action **Index** displays a Login page
2. Controller Action **Login** with `[HttpPost]` takes the model and validates it

In the case, validation fails the URL seems to be set at `http://blah_blah/Users/Login` ( which when requested causes 404 since there is no **Login** action on the controller)

So is creating a Login action only way to solve problem or any other solutions i got ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why can't you rename the `Login` action to `Index`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
   return View();
}
```

or

you can use `ActionName` attribute

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: What if I have multiple post requests on different sections in the view? They all post the same model but have different implementations. They send the same model, because when error occurs, the model needs to be re-populated with values in order to load the view again.

Answer (score 1):

you have to `return View("Index");`

Comment: Sorry for me English. I do that, but the url changes to `http://blah_blah/User/Login` instead of `http://blah_blah/User`, is there anyway i can do that after Post to `Login` action method

Comment: @Deeptechtons return view doesn't change url, only redirect like **dove** answer

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov It returns a `ActionResult` ( View page to login for the User)

Comment: If the problem is 404, you can use my solution and it will works. When you just redirect to action, you will lost your validation information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { returnUrl, errorMessage, etc });
```

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov `TempData` will help him or just create `Index` action with `[HttpPost]` ;)

Comment: I know several methods to do this, but i'm not sure that it is necessary in this case

Comment: updated answer, quite easy to pass the validation data onto the other action. can't see it above but if it took those parameters or you might have a viewmodel object to pass.  this can hold all your validation data too.

Comment: @dove `ViewData`? This is just 302 HTTP redirect. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672143/mvc-passing-data-with-redirecttoaction

Comment: @webdeveloper aye, if they're not mapped from route then TempData would be good.